# Extend gnuplot fillsteps chart's x-range from -Infinity to +Infinity

Tags: gnuplot

I have following code to generate a chart:

```
set terminal dumb size 60, 20
set xrange [2008:2016]
set yrange [-2:16]
plot '-' using 1:2 smooth cumulative with fillsteps

2010 4
2011 -2
2012 6
2013 4
2014 -3
```

which generates this chart:

```
16 +----------------------------------------+
   |    +    +    +     +    +    +    +    |
14 |-+                '-' using 1:2       +-|
12 |-+                       ******       +-|
   |                         *    *         |
10 |-+                       *    *       +-|
 8 |-+                  ******            +-|
   |                    *                   |
 6 |-+                  *                 +-|
 4 |-+       ******     *                 +-|
   |              *     *                   |
 2 |-+            *******                 +-|
 0 |-+                                    +-|
   |    +    +    +     +    +    +    +    |
-2 +----------------------------------------+
  2008 2009 2010 2011  2012 2013 2014 2015 2016
```

It the data describes e.g. the water level of a container, this would be incomplete, as the water level would have been 0 before and the final value afterwards.
So I'm looking for a way to extend the chart accordingly.
The result would be:

```
16 +----------------------------------------+
   |    +    +    +     +    +    +    +    |
14 |-+                '-' using 1:2       +-|
12 |-+                       ******       +-|
   |                         *    *         |
10 |-+                       *    **********|
 8 |-+                  ******            +-|
   |                    *                   |
 6 |-+                  *                 +-|
 4 |-+       ******     *                 +-|
   |         *    *     *                   |
 2 |-+       *    *******                 +-|
 0 |**********                            +-|
   |    +    +    +     +    +    +    +    |
-2 +----------------------------------------+
  2008 2009 2010 2011  2012 2013 2014 2015 2016
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, albeit a pretty hacky one.

The trick is to first render the chart to to dummy terminal and thereby force gnuplot to calculate "gnuplot defined variables".
Those can then be used to append the missing data to the data block.
This works even if the range values are calculated automatically.

```
$data << EOD
2010 4
2011 -2
2012 6
2013 4
2014 -3
EOD

set xrange [2008:2016]
set yrange [-2:16]

set terminal unknown
plot $data

set print $data append
print sprintf("%d 0", GPVAL_X_MIN)
print sprintf("%d 0", GPVAL_X_MAX)
set print

set terminal dumb size 60, 20
plot $data using 1:2 smooth cumulative with fillsteps
```

And voila:

```
$ cat example.gnuplot | gnuplot
WARNING: Plotting with an 'unknown' terminal.
No output will be generated. Please select a terminal with 'set terminal'.


  16 +--------------------------------------------------+
     |     +      +     +      +     +     +      +     |
  14 |-+                        $data using 1:2       +-|
     |                                                  |
  12 |-+                             *******          +-|
  10 |-+                             *     *          +-|
     |                               *     *************|
   8 |-+                       *******                +-|
     |                         *                        |
   6 |-+                       *                      +-|
     |                         *                        |
   4 |-+          *******      *                      +-|
   2 |-+          *     ********                      +-|
     |            *                                     |
   0 |*************                                   +-|
     |     +      +     +      +     +     +      +     |
  -2 +--------------------------------------------------+
    2008  2009   2010  2011   2012  2013  2014   2015  2016
```

However, as you can see, one problem of this solution is that it generates a warning. To hide the warning call it like this: `cat example.gnuplot | gnuplot 2> /dev/null`

Comment: Why do you need the first plot command to let gnuplot determine the x boundaries if you set them manually in the `set xrange` command anyway?

Comment: @user8153 That was just for the example. In the real version I don't set the xrange.